How can i close wsol account
How do I close my wsol account when I have fully redeemed in the Wallet app but still have a little

Since wrapped SOL is an SPL token account, you can retrieve the amount used to create it by closing the account.
using the spl token CLI
spl-token close --address <TOKEN_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> 

ref: https://spl.solana.com/token#example-wrapping-sol-in-a-token
